# Creating a login page using Tkinter -- login verification process not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, authentication, tkinter

I'm attempting to create a login page using Tkinter that connects to a database. The user's details should be stored in the database once registered and then used to verify a user upon logging in. The registration part is working fine, however, there seems to be an error in the login verification process as the program keeps outputting "User Not Found" even when the correct credentials are entered. 
Any insight into why this is happening would be much appreciated!

```
         db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
         db_cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS userdetails")
         db_cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
        for db in db_cursor:
          print(db)
        db_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userdetails.users(userid INT(100) 
        AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, username VARCHAR(255), password VARCHAR(255))")
        db_cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES IN userdetails")
        for table in db_cursor:
          print(table)

 class LoginPage:
   def __init__(self):
      self.userID = 1
      self.mainpage()

def mainpage(self):
    global mainpage
    mainpage = Tk()
    mainpage.geometry("600x600")
    mainpage.title("Login Page")
    mainpage.configure(background="thistle1")
    Label(mainpage, text="Please login or register for a new account", bg="plum2", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Button(mainpage, text="Login",bg="SkyBlue1", height="2", width="30", command=self.login).pack()
    Button(mainpage, text="Register",bg="SkyBlue1", height="2", width="30", command=self.register).pack()
    mainpage.mainloop()

def register(self):
    global register
    global username
    global password
    Label(mainpage, text="Fill in the boxes below to register as a new user", bg="plum2").pack()
    username = str
    username_label = Label(mainpage, text="Username:  ", bg="SkyBlue1").pack()
    usernameRegister_entry = Entry(mainpage, textvariable=username).pack()
    password = str
    password_label = Label(mainpage, text="Password:  ",bg="SkyBlue1").pack()
    passwordRegister_entry = Entry(mainpage, textvariable=password, show='*').pack()
    Button(mainpage, text="Register", width=10, height=1, bg="plum2", command = self.new_user).pack()

def new_user(self):
    self.userID += 1
    userdetails_sql_query = "INSERT INTO userdetails.users VALUES(userID,'username','password')"
    db_cursor.execute(userdetails_sql_query)
    db_connection.commit()
    print(db_cursor.rowcount, "Record Inserted")
    Label(mainpage,text="Registration Success", bg="plum2", font=("calibri", 11)).pack()

def login(self):
    global usernameCheck
    global passwordCheck
    global login
    Label(mainpage, text="Fill in the boxes below to login", bg="plum2").pack()
    usernameCheck = str
    Label(mainpage, text="Username: ", bg="SkyBlue1").pack()
    usernameLogin_entry = Entry(mainpage, textvariable=usernameCheck).pack()
    passwordCheck = str
    Label(mainpage, text="Password: ", bg="SkyBlue1").pack()
    passwordLogin_entry = Entry(mainpage, textvariable=passwordCheck, show= '*').pack()
    Button(mainpage, text="Login", width=10, height=1, bg="plum2", command=self.login_verification).pack()

def login_verification(self):
    sql_select_Query = "select * from userdetails.users"
    db_cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    records = db_cursor.fetchall()
    if usernameCheck in records:
        if passwordCheck in records:
            self.login_success()
        else:
            self.incorrect_password()
    else:
        self.incorrect_user()

def login_success(self):
    global login_success
    Label(mainpage, text="You have logged in successfully!", bg="plum2").pack()
    return self.login_success

def incorrect_password(self):
    Label(mainpage, text="Invalid Password ", bg="plum2").pack()

def incorrect_user(self):
    Label(mainpage, text="User Not Found", bg="plum2").pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not right,

```
    if usernameCheck in records:
        if passwordCheck in records:
            self.login_success()
        else:
            self.incorrect_password()
    else:
        self.incorrect_user()
```

You can iterate the records and for each one check both user and password, but even then that is not the way to do it.

You should build a parametrized query that checks for both user and password and then check if the query returns a record or not.

Something like

```
query = "select * from userdetails.users where user=? and password=?"
    db_cursor.execute(query, (user, password))
    record = db_cursor.fetchall()
    if record:
        self.login_success()
    else:
        self.incorrect_user()
```